# add quotation mark to the value by javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like the following text to appear as '"test test test'" using JavaScript.

```
<body>
    <blockquote>test test test</blockquote>
</body>
```

I have the following code but it does not work

```
<blockquote window.onload = function test()> test test test</blockquote>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName(blockquote).value
    return "a";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `"a"` is simply the string `a`, literally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these will work for you:

**All blockquotes on the page when all HTML elements are in the DOM**:

```
<blockquote>test test test</blockquote>
<blockquote>test2 test2 test2</blockquote>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var bqs = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
        for(var i = 0; i < bqs.length; i++)
            bqs[i].innerHTML = '"'+bqs[i].innerHTML+'"';
    }
</script>
<blockquote>test3 test3 test3</blockquote>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/MGSgQ/)

**All blockquotes on the page above the script**:

```
<blockquote>test test test</blockquote>
<blockquote>test2 test2 test2</blockquote>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var bqs = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
    for(var i = 0; i < bqs.length; i++)
        bqs[i].innerHTML = '"'+bqs[i].innerHTML+'"';
</script>
<blockquote>test3 test3 test3</blockquote>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/nxqyK/)

**Specific blockquote**:

```
<blockquote id="wrapinquotes">test test test</blockquote>
<blockquote>test2 test2 test2</blockquote>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var el = document.getElementById('wrapinquotes');
    el.innerHTML = '"'+el.innerHTML+'"';
</script>
<blockquote>test3 test3 test3</blockquote>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/KmntU/)

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt it be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(){
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote")[0];  //getElementsByTagName returns an array
    var attr = document.createAttribute('value');

     attr.nodeValue = element .value;  //code to set your value.. you need to escape double quotes..

     element .setAttributeNode(attr);
}

</script>

<blockquote window.onload = function test()> test test test</blockquote>
```

if you are trying change the text in the between thr tag then you need to use the innerHTML property..

```
function test(){
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");
        element.innetHTML='"'+element[0].innerHTML+'"';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code wont work is because getElementsByTagName returns a list of all the tags, not just one tag.  So you need to manipulate the list (array).

I found Paulpro's answer helpful, but there are no explanations, so this might help someone.

```
 var bqs = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
```

Get a list of all the blockquote tags.  Call that list bqs

```
for(var i = 0; i < bqs.length; i++)
```

Go through the list bqs once.And while you go down that list:

```
bqs[i].innerHTML = '"'+bqs[i].innerHTML+'"';
```

For each list item execute this code.

This code helps get from trying to execute on a list, to execute on all items on the list.  The last line can be changed to do other things to the list like:
`bqs[i].style.display = 'none';`